# ImageJ compatibility with BufferedImage

Tags: java, image-processing, awt, bufferedimage, imagej

Can I use `BufferedImage` objects from `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` with ImageJ class instances?  For example can I use `BufferedImage` object *instead of* an `ImagePlus` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs for [`ImagePlus(String,java.awt.Image)`](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/ImagePlus.html#ImagePlus%28java.lang.String,%20java.awt.Image%29).

> Constructs an ImagePlus from an Image **or BufferedImage.** ..

**Result:**  Create an `ImagePlus` using that constructor whenever needed.

Comment: didn't notice that..thanks...
i can do it the other way round (Image plus obj -> java.awt.Image)using this right?

http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/ImagePlus.html#getImage()

Comment: ..you might do that or call [`getBufferedImage()`](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/ImagePlus.html#getBufferedImage%28%29) apparently (which I generally prefer). Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Comment: So my question is how to get 16 bit bufferedImage from ij.ImagePlus...? If am trying to get using ShortProcessor it change my signed image to unsigned so i am not getting original image...Thanks in advance can any one provide solution.

Comment: @JayThakkar  You should *ask a question* about that question.

Comment: @JayThakkar  Your problem is not my problem.  If your question asking ability has been curtailed, get that sorted first.

Comment: @Andrew ok my problem is my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void processImage(InputStream inputFile, String outputFilePath, double scaleFactor, int interpolationMethod, double sigmaFactor) {
    try {
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(inputFile);
        ImageProcessor ip = new ColorProcessor(bi);
        ip.blurGaussian(sigmaFactor / scaleFactor);
        ip.setInterpolationMethod(interpolationMethod);
        ImageProcessor outputProcessor = ip.resize((int) (ip.getWidth() * scaleFactor), (int) (ip.getHeight() * scaleFactor));
        IJ.saveAs(new ImagePlus("", outputProcessor), outputFilePath.substring(outputFilePath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1), outputFilePath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Error al comrpimir la imagen: "+e);
    }
}
```